# How to enable 'Instant On' on asus laptop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I have an Asus K55V laptop and I have Windows 7 installed. I have installed Onstant On, but when my laptop goes hibernating and I wake the laptop, it takes about a minute before I am in Windows.

I think this is not correct behavior, I suspect to see the login screen in a few seconds.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asus' instant on mode is activated when you sleep/standby the computer, not hibernate it.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thanks. But my Sleep option is disabled..

Comment: Oh, weird. Is it only disabled when you have instant on enabled, or all the time?

Comment: It was disabled all the time. But I just installed the original graphic card drivers and the Sleep option is now enabled :)

Comment: Awesome, I was just about to say it was probably a driver issue :)